# Remember me functionality without a login form in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way to implement "remember me" functionality in Symfony 2.8 without using a login form at all (neither using generic Symfony means nor FOSUserBundle)?

E.g. I have a popup with a birth date validation form (3 simple fields with day, month, year) and a "remember me" checkbox on a homepage. So user wouldn't see the popup at all when he visits the website next time.

Do I have to use `remeber_me` option in the firewall or just create a session  while handling that birth date validation form (say in a form event listener)?

Comment: Use a custom guard authenticator which reads/sets a cookie that stores the birth-date or stores in/fetches it from the session(-cookie). I'd go with a custom cookie instead of storing the birth-date in the session ... as the session itself might be short-lived or not even needed at all while a user's birthday will never change and therefore could be stored forever.